# Connecting multiple batteries to a battery tender / trickle charger

Tags: battery-charging

I have multiple 12V batteries, some small ATV starter batteries (12Ah and 9Ah) and some deep cycle (120Ah and 97Ah).

1. Can I connect all those batteries to the same battery tender in parallel?
2. Could I get only two chargers one for the small batteries and one for the large one?

At the moment the age of the batteries aren't the same. Some battery at full charge are around 13.4 and some 12.9.

Comment: It probably isn't a good idea to connect such vastly different batteries in parallel for any purpose, including "tending".

Comment: What Dave said, even closely matched batteries will fight each other and self-discharge. Vastly different ones all chained up could behave very oddly. Certainly, you're unlikely to have a good result.

Comment: ok thanks. I won't cheap up and get a 4 bank trickle charger

Answer (score 0):

The Cellink battery has a 12.5V cutoff option so wire with supplied harnesses and an use adequate charger for the main battery.

A 10W battery “tender” may or nay not be adequate because it would need to regulate current to raise the voltage to 14.2 slowly from periods of discharge .  But a smart “tender “ will work.

If it is a simple constant voltage “trickle charger”, that may cause over current protection cycling off and on.